# Pylint not finding errors in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have configured vscode to use pylint.

Workspace Settings:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/home/name/python-venv/machine learning/bin/python3",
"python.linting.pylintPath": "/home/name/python-venv/machine-learning/bin/pylint",
```

The paths link to a virtual python environment.
When I run *Python: Run Linting* from the command prompt (ctrl+P) the output int the output -> Python window is:

```
##########Linting Output - pylint##########
No config file found, using default configuration

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 2.31/10, +7.69)
```

It does not find anything wrong with the file even if it should.
When I run this command from a terminal (with or without active virtual environment) I get the following output:

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module test
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  2, 0: Constant name "hello" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming 
style (invalid-name)
C:  3, 0: Constant name "sess" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming 
style (invalid-name)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 2.50/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, -7.50)
```

Can anyone tell me it behaves like this?

Answer (score 13):

Solved this by manually generating a pylintrc using

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc
```

Now everything works as expected